# Clicking on a specific part of a SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I would like part of my SVG to act as a button and be "clickable". I understand that I can use `<rect>` and Javascript, but I'd have to change the size and position of the rectangle with each different screen resolution.

I was just wondering if there's an easier way to go about doing this?

Here are my code snippets:

example.html

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#svg-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#example {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="svg-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <rect width="9%" height="4%" x="51%" y="60%" />
  </svg>
  <img id="example" src="example.svg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you can't detect what part of SVG was clicked inside an `<img />`. You need to expose SVG into HTML and listen for a click on `rect`.

Comment: @vovchisko May I ask what you mean by "expose SVG into HTML"? Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need to change the rectangle for different resolutions. Use a viewBox and it will adjust automatically.

Comment: @guekling Place SVG right into HTML like in your example. Without using `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here I just put all inside a tag "" and just add the css for the tag

a, a:hover{
text-decoration: none;}

```
<div id="svg-container">
<a href="#">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <rect width="9%" height="4%" x="51%" y="60%" />
    </svg>
</a>
<img id="example" src="example.svg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG can handle dynamic comportment using JavaScript the same way HTML do.

Just use an `embed` tag and put some code in your SVG file:

```html
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="image.svg" />
```